# Update a field from a database and also modify it's length

Tags: sql

Firstly, I don't know how to update a field form a database if I don't know what value it has!
I just know its column and its row(the id)!

I used this, but it didn't work!

`"SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE id=4";

 "UPDATE table_name SET column_name='text' WHERE id=4";`

I also want to modify the column_name length when I update it!

Comment: You need to use an `alter table` statement!

Comment: Before trying to do this in c#, try in pure SQL. This is not a C# question.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?  Your syntax looks correct.

Comment: You cannot change the column name, datatype or size of a field from an `UPDATE` query. You need to use an `ALTER` statement.

Comment: With alter table it gives me an error when I make the column length smaller than it was ... What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried those commands in the other order?  If you do the update first and then select, you'll probably get the new value whereas the way you have it ordered now, it will update after you've done the select.

Comment: @Vlad, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx may help explain more on the datatypes you are using as I think you should learn about the different types before you end up with a rather crazy DB in the end.

Comment: @Vlad, please make sure when you are asking questions that are you clear about where you want help, what you have tried and what kind of environment you have.  If you are programming in Visual Studio 6.0 on Access that is quite different from SQL Server 2012 on Visual Studio 2012 and there are lots of other combinations out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options: 1- you know which property your row has. 2. you want to update all rows regardless of complying with any specific condition(s).

for first case, you need to write UPDATE command, with mentioning WHERE clause and a condition that zero or more rows would comply with.

for the second condition, you have to write UPDATE command without the WHERE clause.

also you need to use ALTER table in a separate command or use a CURSOR.